# Global belongsTo conditions defined in model not being applied (CakePHP v2.4.2)

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, model, model-associations

*Why are my global belongsTo conditions defined within a model not being applied?*

I'm using CakePHP v2.4.2.

In model **Order.php**:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
...,
'Agent' => array(
    'className' => 'Party',
    'foreignKey' => 'agent_id',
    'conditions' => array(...)
),
...
```

In controller **OrdersController.php**:

```
$agents = $this->Order->Agent->find('list');
```

In rendered view the following **SQL statement** is being applied:

```
SELECT `Agent`.`id`, `Agent`.`name` FROM `zeevracht2`.`parties` AS `Agent` WHERE 1 = 1;
```

I tried different conditions, but even a simple string containing `true` isn't being applied (while adding this condition to `PartiesController.php` within a `$this->Order->Agent->find();` works fine:

```
$agents = $this->Order->Agent->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('true')
));
```

leads to:

```
SELECT `Agent`.`id`, `Agent`.`name` FROM `zeevracht2`.`parties` AS `Agent` WHERE true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After collaborating on IRC I found the answer on my own question.

It seems that conditions in the `belongsTo` condition of a model is only applied to the `JOIN` when querying an `Order`.

I was trying to filter `Party` on specific roles, e.g. `Agent`, which is an alias of a `Party` with a role as agent. So the association should be conditioned with a role set as agent. Ideally, this would automatically condition any `$this->Order->Agent->find()` calls. But unfortunately, this is not possible due to a technical issue which is being addressed in the development of version 3 of CakePHP.

The solution is to have two types of conditions on the association: one for the `JOIN` and one for the association itself.

Why one for the `JOIN`? E.g. when a `Post` belongs to `User`, but only `post.validated` should be displayed.

Comment: For those who are interested: I created a Github issue: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2405

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to find the `Agent` that a particular `Order` belongs to, then you should get the record back when querying orders. So something like:

```
<?php
class OrdersController extends AppController {

    public function view($id) {
        $order = $this->Order->findById($id);
        pr($order); exit;
    }
}
```

Should yield something like:

```
Array
(
    [Order] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            …
        )

    [Agent] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            …
        )
)
```

In your question where you then make an additional model call like `$this->Order->Agent->find('list');`, that’s making a *new* query, which will fetch all agents with no conditions. The `conditions` key, where you pass `true`, will have no affect, because that’s not a condition. Conditions should be an array, like this:

```
$this->Order->Agent->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Agent.id' => 1
    )
));
```

But as I say, if your `Order` model belongs to your `Agent` model, then you should get an `Agent` result set back when you get your `Order` result set. If not, try adding the Containable behavior to your `Order` model:

```
<?php
class Order extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array(
        'Containable'
    );
}
```

Comment: My condition is valid, since it _is_ an array. I am not trying to find the `Agent` an `Order` belongs to. This is automatically done by CakePHP via the `foreignKey` option of the `belongsTo` property. I'm trying to filter `Party` with a role set as agent. Containable is added to every model via `AppModel`. I can easily set my desired condition to every `$this->Order->Agent->find();`, but **I do not** want to repeat myself (DRY). I'm using a lot of `find()` calls, it's a big application.

Comment: `'conditions' => array('true')` is *not* a valid array of conditions. You actually need some conditions within that array.

Comment: Are we discussing technical correctness or contextual validity? I agree that simply passing `array('true')` is not valid in its context since you actually need some conditions. `WHERE true` will always evaluate to `true`, just like `WHERE 1=1`, which is basically the same. It's for testing purposes. If you like, I can also use `[model].id=1`. I use the latter also, it just depends on how I feel at the moment ;-). But technical wise, this is fine. CakePHP simply adds any standalone string in the array into a WHERE clause.
I'd love to discuss this with you more, but lets focus on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
...,
'Agent' => array(
    'className' => 'Party',
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'conditions' => array('joinField'=>'joinedField', ...more conditions)
),
```